# Parsing unknown object in Java

Tags: java, android, parsing

I'm developing an android application, where I get some object from a .NET web service using SOAP. I have no problem getting my object. I use ksoap2-android to handle the request.

I need a good way to parse this object's types to a complementary Java object. Anyone knows a good way to do this?

It's composed of simple types and other objects composed of simple types.

The only way I know right now, is something like:

```
String[] types =  o.toString().split(";");
```

Then parse the string array. There most be an more convenient way to do it?

OK an example would be a good idea, so here's one of my objects:

> anyType{Success=true;
>   UserMessage=anyType{};
>   TechnicalMessage=anyType{};
>   IntValue=0; DoubleValue=0;
>   DateTimeValue=0001-01-01T00:00:00;
>   AgeGroups=anyType{};
>   SessionConfigurations=anyType{Client_SessionConfiguration=anyType{ID=2;
>   Name=Skoleklasser; };
>   Client_SessionConfiguration=anyType{ID=3;
>   Name=Virksomheder; };
>   Client_SessionConfiguration=anyType{ID=4;
>   Name=Gæster; }; }; }

Comment: On a pedantic note, aren't all objects composed of simple types and other objects?

Answer (score 1):

I call lots of web services from android. I extend the org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler class to handle the response.

```
public class BaseXMLResponseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    StringBuffer accumulator = new StringBuffer();


    @Override
    public void characters(char[] buffer, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
          accumulator.append(buffer, start, length);
    }
}
```

Then just implement the methods

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
```

For example:

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {  
accumulator.setLength(0);  // Ready to accumulate new text
}

List<String> testElements = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException
{

            if (localName.equals("testelement")) {  
                    testElements.add(accumulator.toString());
                }
    }

    List<String> getElements() {
    return testElements;
    }
```

Comment: I use kSoap-android to handle the SOAP... My problem is only to find an easy way to serialize my object in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking **"How do I serialize and deserialize Java objects?"**

Try [JSON](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/JSON).

Google offers a good JSON parsing library called [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

**The answer to this question depends a lot on what format your object is in**; how about posting a sample?

Comment: Other options: Google Protobuffs and XML.

Comment: I included an example of the object in my post. Hope this the right way to do it? and not to post another.

Comment: unfortunately I don't know anything about using ksoap2. I did notice many tutorials when doing an online search though.